# how to join two table in sql (php)

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

1) user_reg

```
user_id
user_name
full_name
mobile_number
```

2) products

```
user_id
pro_id
pro_name
pro_desc
Pro_price
```

How to fetch value of all **fields** from both tables where **pro_id** is equal to 6

Comment: How to join two tables is probably the most basic question in SQL. You were not able to find the answer anywhere on the Internet?

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
SELECT * FROM user_reg FULL OUTER JOIN products ON (user_reg.user_id = products.user_id)
```

See that: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp